# Using CSS for text and images that grow and shrink with page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ideally, the text and images (except the buttons at the bottom) would grow/shrink with page re-size and stay in alignment but then stop shrinking at some % of it's original size. Say 30%. I am open to using CSS or jQuery or both.

What is the best/cleanest method to do this?

See my code at: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZCMV/

OR:

HTML:

```
<html><head></head><body id="page_welcome">
<div class="wrapper">    
<div class="main">
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://qa.tweetcaster.com/assets/img/home/logo.png"></div>
    <div class="tagline">
        <div>The best thing to happen to Twitter since Twitter</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="download">
            <div>Over 10 million users! Get TweetCaster FREE:</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="devices">
            <li><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.tweetcaster&referrer=utm_source%3DTCwebsite%26utm_medium%3Dweb%26utm_campaign%3DTCwebsite" target="_blank"><img src="https://qa.tweetcaster.com/assets/img/home/play_store.png" alt="TweetCaster for Android"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tweetcaster-for-twitter/id420792544?mt=8" target="_blank"><img src="https://qa.tweetcaster.com/assets/img/home/app_store.png" alt="TweetCaster for iPhone and iPad"></a></li>
            <li><a href="/login" id="web"><img src="https://qa.tweetcaster.com/assets/img/home/web.png" alt="TweetCaster web app"></a></li>
            <li>
                <button id="dropdown_button" class="menu_button"><img src="https://qa.tweetcaster.com/assets/img/home/more.png" alt="More" ></button>                    
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="http://tweetcaster.uservoice.com/forums/183240-tweetcaster-web" class="feedback" target="_blank">Feedback</a> &#169;
            <a href="http://onelouder.com" target="_blank">Onelouder</a> 
            <a href="http://tweetcaster.com/privacy" target="_blank">Privacy</a>
            <a href="http://onelouder.com/#terms" target="_blank">Terms</a> 
            <a href="http://onelouder.com/#about" target="_blank">About</a> 
            <a href="http://support.onelouder.com" target="_blank">Help</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bird"><img src="https://qa.tweetcaster.com/assets/img/home/bird.png" alt="TweetCaster"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
    background: #7bc5ef url(https://qa.tweetcaster.com/assets/img/layout/bg.jpg) center top repeat-x;
    padding-top: 15%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.main {
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 550px;
}
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
.logo {
    margin: 30px 0px 0px;
}
.tagline {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 10);
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 510px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 550px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.download {
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.links {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.links a {
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #282828;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.links a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.feedback {
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.devices li {
    display: inline-block;
    display: inline; /*ie7 fix */
    padding-right: 7px;
}
.devices {
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.other_devices {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.other_devices li {
    display: inline-block;
    display: inline; /*ie7 fix */
    padding-right: 6px;
}
.bird img {
    float: right;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    float: right;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -10;
    _position: absolute;
    _top:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop+ (document.documentElement.clientHeight-this.offsetHeight)));
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: -4%;
    min-height: 400px;
    min-width: 181px;
}
.menu_button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    margin-left: -7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden_menu {
    background-color: white;
    color: #000;
    height: 328px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 480px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    left: 40px;
    top: 89px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
 .get_tc {
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.dd_arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.tc_pink {
    padding-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.get_tc {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.windows_button {
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.clear:before, .clear:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block !important;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clear {
    zoom: 1;
} /* IE < 8 */
p {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
p:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
table, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, caption {
    color: #888;
}
​
```

Comment: My personal opinion is that you should look into using HTML5/CSS3, you will find it is easily optimised for resizeable content. You can use Media queries to determine the resolution used to view your website and can instruct differently depending on each query.

Comment: Sounds like responsive design to me. Here's a huge list of resources, http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize CSS3 Media Queries to resize your page depending on the browser, and/or device size.
Heres a great article to get you started: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

As for the images, if you set up a container with a width percentage of the page you can add the following to the pages css to make them resposive and resize to the window size.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This'll make images resize on your page without the use of media queries, but if you're looking for a more custom fit for each browser/device size, you'll definitely want to go with media queries.

Hope this helps!